# Error function in Python 2

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following python code.

```
def nhap(a, b):
   a = input("Enter number a: ")
   b = input("ENter number  b: ")


def plus(a, b):
    nhap(a, b)
    print "Sum 2 so la: ", a + b

def minus(a, b):  
     nhap(a, b)
     print "Minus 2 so la: ", a - b

def asterisk(a, b):
     nhap(a, b)
     print "Asterisk 2 so la: ", a*b

def slash(a, b):
    nhap(a, b)
    print "Slash 2 so la: ", a/b

def start(): 
   while True:
      print "==================="
      print "[0] Enter number"
      print "[1] Sum"
      print "[2] except"
      print "[3] asterisk"
      print "[4] slash"
      print "[5] exit"
      print "==================="
      num = raw_input().strip()
      if num == '0':
        nhap(a, b)
      elif num == '1':
        cong(a, b)
      elif num == '2':
        tru(a, b)
      elif num == '3':
        nhan(a, b)
      elif num == '4':
        chia(a, b)
      elif num == '5':
        exit()
start()
```

When I run my program, I receive the following output and error.

```
===================
[0] Enter number
[1] Sum
[2] except
[3] asterisk
[4] slash
[5] exit
===================
0


Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "abc.py", line 46, in <module>

start()

File "abc.py", line 35, in start

 nhap(a, b)

NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

How can I call the function `nhap()` properly to accept two numbers and perform the correct math operation?

Comment: in your `start` function you don't have these two variables instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You get `a` and `b` in the function `nhap`. Note, it doesn't accept `a` and `b`, but get them from the console input and return. What we need is to make it return them as a tuple. Here we go:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def nhap():
   a = input("Enter number a: ")
   b = input("ENter number  b: ")
   return (a, b)

def plus():
    (a,b) = nhap()
    print "Sum 2 so la: ", a + b

def minus():  
    (a, b) = nhap()
    print "Minus 2 so la: ", a - b

def asterisk():
    (a, b) = nhap()
    print "Asterisk 2 so la: ", a*b

def slash():
    (a, b) = nhap()
    print "Slash 2 so la: ", a/b

def start(): 
    while True:

       print "Enter number"
       print "==================="
       print "[1] Sum"
       print "[2] except"
       print "[3] asterisk"
       print "[4] slash"
       print "[nother button] exit"
       print "==================="

       num = raw_input().strip()        
       if num == '1':
           plus()
       elif num == '2':
           minus()
       elif num == '3':
           asterisk()
       elif num == '4':
           slash()
       else:
           exit()
start()
```

What should be added/fixed: handling non-digits inputs in the `nhap` function. I left it to you.;)

Comment: @KevinKien is everything sorted out now?